# Conditional jobs and steps based on updated paths

Tags: maven, github-actions

We're using GitHub Actions for our project's multi-module Maven CI build at https://github.com/ibm/fhir.

We have:

- a minimal set of tests we'd like to run on each pull request; and
- a set of comprehensive tests that we'd like to run only when a given module (or its dependencies) has been updated

I found that I can accomplish something like this by defining multiple workflows and using the built-in `on.pull_request.paths` property as documented at:  https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpaths

What I'm wondering is whether/how I can accomplish something similar at the `job` or `step` level.  I found that jobs support conditional execution based on https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idif but I can't tell if there is anything to help get behavior similar to the `on.pull_request.paths` feature.

Assuming not, has anyone found an action to help with this?  Or maybe someone can point me at the implementation of that `on.pull_request.paths` feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to create a step that does what I need by using `git diff` to diff the `github.base_ref` branch with the latest PR commit (`${GITHUB_SHA}`) and filter the output to select paths. The gotchas were that:

- I needed to use the `github['base_ref']` syntax (presumably due to the underscore?)
- The base_ref branch doesn't exist in the cloned repo, so I needed to prefix that with `origin/`

```
    - name: Conditional test
      env:
        BASE: origin/${{ github['base_ref'] }}
      run: |
        paths=(
          path1
          path2/src
          path3/src/main
        )
        if [ -n "$(git --no-pager diff --name-only ${BASE} ${GITHUB_SHA} -- ${paths[@]})" ]; then
          echo "Changes affect module, running ALL"
          mvn -B test -P all-tests --no-transfer-progress
        else
          echo "No changes affect module, running MINIMAL"
          mvn -B test -P minimal-tests --no-transfer-progress
        fi
```

I havn't had enough experience with GitHub actions to know if we're better off encapsulating that kind of logic in a custom action, but for now I'm just gonna go with this in order to avoid the extra external dependency.

Answer (score 1):

This post on the community forums may help.
https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/What-happened-to-github-event-head-commit-modified/m-p/37736#M3066

The original poster there has a similar issue and they created the following action to determine if there are modifications to a list of paths. I'm not sure if this works just as well with `on: pull_request`, but you could try it and see.

https://github.com/marketplace/actions/path-watcher-action

Example from the `path-watcher-action` repository:

```
on: [push]

jobs:
  job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - id: modified
        uses: pheel/path-watcher-action@v1
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          paths: 'dir1/**/*,dir2/**/*'
      - if: steps.modified.outputs.modified
        run: echo "Hey some change happened in one of your watched paths!"
```

Comment: Thanks!  I also managed to get something going without introducing a custom action and will write a separate answer for that.  Finally, I found the `netlify/actions/diff-includes` action at https://github.com/netlify/actions/tree/master/diff-includes but didn't try it out since I already got something that works for me.