# How to conditionally trigger a Github Workflow based which directory a change is pushed to?

Tags: github-actions

This is from the [Github Workflow Documentation:](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#on)

You can exclude paths using the ! character. The order that you define patterns matters:

A matching negative pattern (prefixed with !) after a positive match will exclude the path.
A matching positive pattern after a negative match will include the path again.
This example runs anytime the push event includes a file in the sub-project directory or its subdirectories, unless the file is in the sub-project/docs directory. For example, a push that changed sub-project/index.js or sub-project/src/index.js will trigger a workflow run, but a push changing only sub-project/docs/readme.md will not.

```
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'sub-project/**'
      - '!sub-project/docs/**'
```

I understand that if a change is pushed ***only*** in `sub-project/docs/**` path, the workflow will not trigger.
With the current setup, the workflow will be triggered when a change is pushed in `sub-project/**` irrespective of the fact that if a change is pushed in any of the `!` paths or not.

I am trying to find a way to trigger (or not trigger) a workflow based on the following condition:
Trigger the workflow if a change is pushed in `sub-project/**`. However, do not trigger the workflow if a change is pushed in any of the paths denoted by `!` in the same commit. Is there a way to trigger the flow based on the above condition?

Comment: Did you try using the `paths-ignore` ? [reference](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-positive-and-negative-patterns)

Comment: @GuiFalourd Yes, however, I am not able to achieve the behavior that I need using `paths-ignore` as I still want to trigger the workflow if the change is pushed in `sub-project/**`. The only difference is that I DO NOT want to trigger workflow if the change is pushed in `sub-project/docs/` as well. So I need a way to check if a change was pushed in `sub-project/docs/`, don't even bother triggering the flow no matter what.

Comment: I was thinking about using both `paths: - 'sub-project/**'` and `paths-ignore: '!sub-project/docs/**'`, but it probably doesn't work as both triggers condition will be treated separately...

Comment: I guess [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58808690/conditional-jobs-and-steps-based-on-updated-paths) is related to what you want to achieve, with possible answers. Have you take a look at those workaround solutions yet?

Comment: @GuiFalourd `path-watcher-action` looks interesting. Will try and see if it works for my use case. Thank you for the reference.

Comment: @YashShrivastava did you already try action `path-watcher-action`  & did it work?