# GitHub Actions workflow support for multiple folders using on push

Tags: github, github-actions

Is it possible to call a specific workflow depending on the path that triggers a `push` event?

I.e. Can I specify that if a change is made to `projects/abc/**` then use/call: `xyz/buildpipeline/.github/workflows/ci.yml@0.0.1`

but if a change has been made to `projects/def/**` then use/call:
`xyz/buildpipeline/.github/workflows/deploy.yml@2.0.1`

**.github/workflows/caller.wf.yml**: I would be hoping to add `projects/def/**` in here somehow.

```
---
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'projects/abc/**'
jobs:
  call-ci-workflow:
    uses: xyz/buildpipeline/.github/workflows/ci.yml@0.0.1
```

Comment: You could do this with separate workflows for each path. Then you can use the built in path filter. Or see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58808690/conditional-jobs-and-steps-based-on-updated-paths) for how to filter jobs/steps by path.   There is no way to modify the name/tag of the action being used at runtime.